# JavaFX error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 > -2

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to build a simple window with JavaFX using SceneBuilder. My fxml file is pretty simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="rangel.erlan.ui.ControladorUsuarios">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="250.0" layoutY="205.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="This is just a test" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main (UI.java).

```
package rangel.erlan.ui;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UI extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Usuarios.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Formulario de Ingreso de Usuarios");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 625, 450));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

The compilation process is successful. I use the following command to run the application:

`java --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-20-openjdk/lib/javafx_modules/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -cp bin src/rangel/erlan/ui/UI.java`

But this is the error I get from that:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 > -2
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3782)
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3742)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:447)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:205)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

I am using Arch Linux and the latest OpenJFX, with which I had issues when running the application due to the javafx lib path. I solve it by creating a new directory containing all the javafx modules that I need. After that, the only error I am getting is the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 > -2`.
Everything is supposed to be working correctly but not sure what this issues is and not sure how to solve it.

Comment: From the Javadoc: `Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if from > to`.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Yes, but note the stack trace shows the error is coming from the compiler, not the OP's code.

Comment: @TateyRG Your command is wrong. The `src/rangel/erlan/ui/UI.java` means you're using the ["launch single source file programs"](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) feature added in Java 11. And that means that file is being compiled into memory and then executed. Why that would lead to the error you're seeing, I'm not sure. But try to use the correct `java` command to see if that gets rid of the error. That means using the _fully qualified class name_ instead of the source file path: `rangel.erlan.ui.UI`. That will use the already-compiled code from your previous invocation of `javac`.

Comment: Make sure you can get `HelloFX` running in your environment, following the instructions at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx).  After that, adopt the process for your code (or use the more sophisticated options at openjfx.io that detail maven/gradle build tool use and/or IDE use).

Comment: @jewelsea, the `HelloFX` works fine. But applying the `HelloFX` code on mine I get this error:
```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rangel.erlan.ui.UI
```
This is after compiling and running the .class file created inside `src/rangel/erlan/ui/`

Comment: Rather than doing this all manually on the command line, I strongly suggest using a build tool (Maven or Gradle) to handle compiling, running, etc. your project, plus an IDE to help with development. That said, if the class file ended up under `src/rangel/erlan/ui`, then did you change `-cp bin` to `-cp src`? Or you could put the class files in `bin` with `-d bin`.

Comment: I wanted to do this manually to avoid installing an IDE and  thought that it would be easy to compile and run myself. As a temporary solution I just installed IntelliJ and it seems to be working fine.
However, I won't give up. Not sure what the IDE is doing that Im not.

Comment: Java on the command line is not particularly user-friendly. That's one of the reasons build tools (e.g., Maven, Gradle, etc.) are so popular in the Java ecosystem (another major reason is dependency management, plus all the other build related things build tools can do, such as testing, code analyzers, formatting, etc.). IDEs can do a lot of those things too, but build tools are more "general"/"IDE-independent". In short, I would _not_ recommend developing in Java without a build tool or an IDE (the latter especially for code completion, quick documentation, refactoring support, etc.).

Comment: Though for relatively simple Java projects, forgoing a build tool should be okay.